# Pytorch is creating non empty Tensor with torch.empty((x,y)

Tags: pytorch

I just want to create an empty tensor containing only zero values. but here is what I am getting so far. Source: https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.empty.html

```
a=torch.empty((2,3), dtype=torch.int32, device = 'cuda')
a

tensor([[16843009,        1,        1],
    [       0,        1,        0]], device='cuda:0', dtype=torch.int32)
```

Screenshot as proof:

[image]

My question is, Why?? Is it a bug or what

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want a tensor of zeros, use `torch.zeros`.

`torch.empty` allocates a tensor but it does not initialise the contents, meaning that the tensor will contain whatever data happened to occupy that region of memory already.

Comment: Thank you. I wish they have mentioned it in official documentation. as there they show the output of zeros.